# Unity - Custom Inspector non-editable array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm creating a voxel game for fun while on vacation and i came across Custom Inspector and Editors, to make my life easier when creating new voxels.

The problem is: a simple voxel has a mesh composed of an array of 6 faces, each index corresponding to one direction, for example, the north face is the face of index 0, the upper face is index 4, and so on. But if i leave the inspector to show the array as it is, it's not guaranteed that each face will be placed on the right index.

My idea is to create the custom inspector and make it reorganize the array, the script of the editor would contain a new array "faces" (see the code below), that receive a face and a direction, and show in the inspector, making it possible . The current code is:

```js
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(VoxelMesh))]
public class VoxelMeshEditor: Editor {

  public enum DirectionEnum {
    North,
    East,
    South,
    West,
    Up,
    Down,
    Other,
    Special,
    All
  }

  [Serializable]
  public struct DirectionalFace {
    public DirectionEnum direction;
    public Face face;
  }

  [SerializeField] private DirectionalFace[] faces;
  private SerializedObject soEditor;
  private SerializedProperty spFaces;

  private void OnEnable() {
    soEditor = new SerializedObject(this);
    spFaces = soEditor.FindProperty("faces");
  }

  public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
    base.OnInspectorGUI();

    if (EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(spFaces, true)) {
      soEditor.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

It creates an unchangeable array, i cannot edit it. How can i make it editable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Serialized data are saved to disk, ie: .asset or .unity scene files, even if your approach worked, your data will only live until the next assembly reload (when the Editor project is recompiled, ie: on any Editor script change).

Comment: Even when "VoxelMesh" is a ScriptableObject?

Comment: The "VoxelMesh" ScriptableObject is written to the asset file it points to. However, in that case you're working with a serialized "VoxelMeshEditor". You could try a different approach, where the extra structures are either part of "VoxelMesh" itself (optionally with UNITY_EDITOR conditionals) accessed through the "serializedObject" property of the Editor class, or create them as instance fields in the Editor class and init them at each load (I suggest this approach).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the DirectionalFace[] faces variable from private to public.

Comment: Read about the SetDirty() method

Comment: From the documentation itself: "The dirty flag is used internally to find changed assets that need to be saved to disk", I can't even edit the array yet, tried to use the SetDirty and nothing changed.